# Trouble displaying documents from firestore with a React js frontend

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

Hi I'm relatively new to React js and I'm trying to create a mapping app where users can find a saved farm by searching for it using a search function. So far I can get the results of my queries in firestore ([Database[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdXVn.png)) by console.log and also by displaying this information as a Json object ([output of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdH5V.png)). I'd really like to just display the locality and the coordinates of the farm but haven't managed to be able to pull just those things out. I have tried data.id and data.locality but it doesn't work. Not sure where I'm going wrong, any help would be much appreciated thanks. Here is my code:

`

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
// import ProjectList from './ProjectList'
import { compose } from 'redux'
import { firestoreConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase'
import firebase from '../config/fbConfig'

const searchTerm = 'Methven'
const projRef = firebase.firestore().collection('projects')

let data

export function Trip4 () {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([])
  const [title, setTitle] = React.useState('')

  React.useEffect(() => {
    projRef
      .where('locality', '==', `${searchTerm}`)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        setData(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          title: doc.data().title,
          content: doc.data().content,
          locality: doc.data().locality,
          ...doc.data()
        })))
        console.log('All data in *projects* collection in useEffect: ', data)
      })
    setTitle(JSON.stringify(data))
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='card'>
          <p>{console.log(`the output of data: ${data}`)}</p>
          {
            JSON.stringify(data)
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  // console.log(state)
  return {
    projects: state.firestore.ordered.projects,
    auth: state.firebase.auth,
    profile: state.firebase.profile,
  }
}

export default compose(connect(mapStateToProps), firestoreConnect([{ collection: 'projects' }]))(Trip4)
```

`

EDIT : Based on Magnus' answer I found something which worked, slightly re-tweaked [image: The result]`

```
<div className='card'>
          <p>{console.log(`the output of data: ${data}`)}</p>
          {data != undefined ? data.map((item) => ( <p>{item.id + ' - ' + item.locality}</p>)) : null}
        </div>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<div className='card'>
   <p>{console.log(`the output of data: ${data}`)}</p>
   {data != undefined ? data.map(item => {
      <p>{item.id + " - " + item.locality}</p>
   }) : null}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, moved things around a bit so it would work but yeah really worked thank you. I'll add the solution to the orginal post